# Why does rotation happens about hinge point in a bar when net force acting on it are zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

[image: two equal and opposite force acts on the rod]
I have asked this question previously but not got any proper answer relevant to its free body diagram.Few are saying the body will not be in translational equilibrium as a horizontal force will appear at hinge but how that force will appear because that point is stationary.Please anyone explain i am confused?

Comment: 1. This is not a FBD. An FBD removes the hinge and replaces it with its reaction. 2. Are you ignoring the weight of the bar?

Comment: Yes this is not the fbd nor i am ignoring weight,but weight will be in vertical direction balanced by vertical hinge force and how the horizontal hinge force will develop if the rod net force is zero in horizontal direction already.I can't visualise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does rotation happens about hinge point in a bar when net force
> acting on it are zero?

The short answer is because there is a net torque about the hinge pin caused by two equal, opposite, and parallel forces which constitute a force-couple, or simply a "couple", resulting in no net force on the bar. From the free body diagram (FBD) of FIG 1 below, the sum of the horizontal forces is

$$\sum F_{H}=R_{H}+P-P=0$$
$$R_{H}=0$$

The sum of the moments (torques) about the hinge pin, taking counter-clockwise torque as positive is

$$\sum M=\frac{5}{6}PL-\frac{1}{4}PL=\frac{7}{12}PL$$

Notice that this same torque about the hinge could be produced by a single force $P$ applied a distance $\frac{7}{12}L$ from the pin. However, in order for there to be no net horizontal force on the bar, we would then require a horizontal reaction at the hinge of $R_{H}=-P$.

What makes a couple unique is that the moment about *any point* along the bar, including the COM and the hinge, is the same and equals $\frac{7}{12}PL$. For this reason a couple is called a "free vector", meaning it can be moved anywhere on the body, including the hinge, and have the same external effect on the body. See FIG 2. FIG 2 is equivalent to FIG 1 with the free moment vector moved to the hinge. To further understand why, see the accepted answer to this question: [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535963/force-couple-off-centre-of-mass-in-space#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=Net%20force%20is%20zero%20so,about%20the%20centre%20of%20mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535963/force-couple-off-centre-of-mass-in-space#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=Net%20force%20is%20zero%20so,about%20the%20centre%20of%20mass).

CONCLUSION: The net torque at the hinge, assumed to be ideal (frictionless), produced by the couple (a free vector) causes the COM to rotate counter clockwise about the hinge. Because the net torque is produced by a couple, instead of a single force, there is no horizontal reaction at the hinge.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So,final conclusion is that due to acceleration of center of mass in case of ideal hinge a horizontal net force will develop at the hinge and in case of real hinge a moment will develop and the door will not move.

Comment: I have included the final conclusion in an update to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please once again read what you are saying sir just shifting the couple forces does not change the fact that"when net force is zero the body can only rotate about its center of mass".

Comment: @HIMANSHUKUMAR. What I am saying is the couple is a free vector than can moved anywhere along the body. But that doesn’t mean the bar can rotate anywhere along the body. That depends on whether or not the body is constrained so that rotation can ONLY occur at particular location. If the bar were not constrained by the hinge (and ignoring translational motion due to gravity) you would have pure rotation and that rotation can only occur about the COM, regardless of the fact that the mid-point between the P forces is not the COM. Instead you have pure rotation about the hinge.

Comment: The link I gave you provides the proof. But this bar is not free to rotate about the COM because of the hinge restraint, and can only rotate about the hinge.  I’m sorry, but I no more time to spend on this. Sorry it apparently hasn’t answered your question. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry sir i think i have irritated you but the only thing i am not able to digest where is the net force which is causing the center of mass of this body to move

Comment: @HIMANSHUKUMAR You did not irritate me. It just appears I am unable to help you. One last try: It is net torque that initiates rotation of the COM about the hinge, not a net force. Perhaps you are thinking about the centripetal force which is a net force responsible for maintaining the circular motion.  The centripetal force is directed towards the center of rotation (hinge pin). For your example, ignoring gravity (as in outer space) the centripetal force on the COM is equal to: $$\frac{mv^2}{L/2}$$ Where $v$ is the speed of the COM.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't rotation happen? That is dependent upon torque, not force. Translational and rotational equilibrium are independent of each other. Moreover, the object is not at translational equilibrium here because of because of a hinge force, the magnitude of which you can calculate this way:

1. Find out torque about hinge.
2. Using this information, find out angular acceleration of rod.
3. Hence, Find out acceleration of CM of rod.
4. Use Newton's Second law to find out horizontal component of hinge force.

Comment: Please try to understand my question when the forces are balanced the center of mass is at rest as in this case then why would the hinge horizontal force come especially when the rod is already in equilibrium means can you tell the process how the horizontal force develops in hinge

Comment: The forces are not balanced, you are ignoring hinge force. I already said why hinge force develops. There is torque, so com  accelerates. That is impossible if forces balance. So hinge force acts.

Comment: I am ignoring because the rod is already balanced by forces so how will the force has hinge develop as this point cannot move if a force especially develop at that point a reaction force will also come by the wall

Comment: If an unbalanced force is applied to a point it does not mean that that point has to move. It means the COM has to move.

Comment: @HIMANSHUKUMAR, equilibrium requires zero net translational force AND zero net torque.  You have zero net translational force.  However, your pivot point is at the hinge, not at the COM.  This means that, given the definition of torque, you do NOT have zero net torque on the bar, and it will rotate counter-clockwise as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two P's represent equal horizontal forces acting at equal distances from the center of mass, then the associated torques would tend to rotate the rod about the CM without moving the CM.  This rotation would require the ends of the rod to move relative to the CM. But, the upper end is constrained by the axle which would have to exert a horizontal force to prevent such motion. For rotation about the axle, the two torques are not equal.

Comment: Which two torques are you talking about in last line

Comment: The torques from the two P's about the hinge.

Comment: Means you want to say that if the forces were as such that they create equal torque then the net torque would be zero about that hinge point and the rod will not rotate but here in this case the rod will rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine what would happen if the rod was not hinged, it would rotate about a the COM of rod (and not about mid point of forces (see [Farcher's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535963/force-couple-off-centre-of-mass-in-space#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=Net%20force%20is%20zero%20so,about%20the%20centre%20of%20mass)). The Hinge reaction develops to counter this rotation resulting in a net force on the COM of the rod.

The hinge reaction is the reason why the COM of the rod moves.

Comment: FYI Although intuitively it would seem that if the rod was not hinged it would rotate about the midpoint between the P forces (I used to think so too), it will, in fact, always rotate about the COM.  See Farcher's answer in the link I provided.

Comment: @Bob D Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

the answer is pretty simple... :)

The thing is here the rod is not an isolated system. The rod is connected to a VERY MASSIVE wall through a hinge. So the net force due to $P$ ​equals zero means that the centre of mass of the whole system... including wall and rod remains stationary, which is true...

if the rod was isolated and free, then your argument would have been correct. It would rotate about rod's COM.

Note : By considering the reaction force from the hinge, we are essentially taking the rod out from the rod+wall system. And hence, all other answers here explain the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple philosophy to understand the deal with forces and torques:

Action of forces of force vector at any point on a rigid body, given that it's in the same direction, causes the exact same acceleration but different torque. The idea is that the rotation experienced by the body due to the pushes and pulls you give it depends on the location of force.

For a more mathematical treatment, see Kleppner and Kolenkow.