# Why do unfixed objects always rotate about their centre of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, torque

Statement: I understand similar questions have been asked; however, none of them really helps me.

The detailed version of my question is as follows:
**Why do unconstrained and unfixed objects always rotate about the lines passing through their CMs when a constant tangential forces are applied to them?** I understand that if an object does not rotate about its CM, then its rotation will decay to the rotation about the axis passing through its CM.

I would like to have a **mathematical proof** since a proof using Reductio ad absurdum has been made by a person from another forum -- he argued that if the axis of rotation is not the centre of mass, then the torque created by the force will cause the centre of mass to accelerate, which is a violation of Newton's laws of motion. Thank you.

**Edit:** The [proof](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/readings/MIT8_01F16_chapter20.pdf) (Appendix 20A) has been found. A big thank you to Farcher.

Comment: Lots of answers here:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311606/why-a-body-always-rotate-about-its-center-of-mass/311616#311616

Comment: @mikestone 1. No tangential forces are applied, so the situation is slightly different. 2. No math.